# The "Created" property of an ActiveX object always false

Tags: c#-4.0, activex

I wrote something as simple as below:

```
//...
this.Middleware = new AxMELFARXMLib.AxMelfaRxM();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.Middleware)).BeginInit();
        this.Middleware.Name = "Middleware";
        this.Middleware.OcxState = ((AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("Middleware.OcxState")));
        this.Middleware.MsgRecvEvent += new System.EventHandler(this.Message_receiv_event_handler);
        this.Middleware.Visible = false;
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.Middleware)).EndInit();
        this.Middleware.CreateControl();
        while(Middleware.Created == false)
        {

        }
```

Before the while loop, if peeped by the VS debugger, the "Created" property of "Middleware" is true, as shown below
[image]

However, when executed, the program is always trapped by the while loop, which checks if the "Created" property is of value false. The code snippet is in the same function, a constructor actually, and is executed by a single thread. This just doesn't make any sense to me.

Observation: If a breakpoint is inserted before the while loop, and one waits long enough before continue, the "Created" property becomes true, and execution just continues without trapped in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening here is you are blocking the thread the creation happen in. Just await asynchronously and you should be fine.

Comment: The piece of code is wrapped and called using the message loop apartment in your other post about wrapping ActiveX object. there is a Apartment.Run(...).Wait() there.

Comment: This has nothing to do with my comment above. Please read carefully. I am talking about awaiting the creation in this piece of code